# Gradle Android Unit Tests with module dependency leads to NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

I am struggling with a JUnit run configuration.

- Module A

  - main
- Module B

  - main
  - tests

Module B uses Module A

I am trying to run unit tests in **Module B**. I have a dependency defined in build.gradle of **Module B**

```
compile project(':moduleA')
```

It works fine in Android Studio, but when I want to get it running with gradle command line:

```
gradlew :moduleB:testDebugUnitTest
```

It leads to failure for some tests with `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`, so I guess it cannot find the classes in **Module A**. I've checked the /build/intermediates/classes folder and the compiled classes are there. I've also tried to add a test dependency:

```
testCompile project(':moduleA')
```

But it did not make any difference. I also tried to clean/rebuild and run on two machines. Build with gradle plugin 1.5 and gradle 2.9 and 2.11.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35917846/gradle-android-unit-tests-that-depend-on-multiple-module?rq=1
I have the same issue and didn't found any solution yet.

Comment: I encounter the same problem, any update @marcin-kunert?

Comment: @fchristysen, unfortunately not, we merged some modules together and no longer have to face this issue

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you do not have Proguard enabled for you build?

Comment: Yes, I am sure.